# MPI all-to-all communication issue

Tags: c++, mpi

I am communicating large vectors between processes for a numerical simulation. Everything works fine until a certain time step. I don't get errors, but the output solution is obviously incorrect.

I am debugging for quite a while now and my assumption is that there is an error in the MPI communication.

The communication part of my code looks like this:

```
MPI_Request req;
for(int j=0;j<numProcs;j++){
    if(j!=myId){
        tag=0;
        sizeToSend=toProc[j].size();
        MPI_Isend(&sizeToSend, 1, MPI_LONG_LONG, j, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD,&req);
        MPI_Request_free(&req);
    }
}
for(int j=0;j<numProcs;j++){
    if(j!=myId){
        tag=0;
        MPI_Recv(&sizeToReceive[j], 1, MPI_LONG_LONG, j, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
    }
}
for(int j=0;j<numProcs;j++){
    if(j!=myId){
        if(toProc[j].size()>0){
            tag=1;
            MPI_Isend(&toProc[j][0], toProc[j].size(), MPI_LONG_LONG, j, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD,&req);
            MPI_Request_free(&req);
        }
    }
}
for(int j=0;j<numProcs;j++){
    if(j!=myId){
        if(sizeToReceive[j]>0){
            receiveBuffer.resize(sizeToReceive[j]);
            tag=1;
            MPI_Recv(&receiveBuffer[0], sizeToReceive[j], MPI_LONG_LONG, j, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
            for(int k=0;k<sizeToReceive[j];k++){
                domain.field[receiveBuffer[k]]=1;
            }
            receiveBuffer.clear();
        }
    }
}
MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
for(int j=0;j<toProc.size();j++){
    toProc[j].clear();
}
```

The variable `numProcs` is an int containing the number of processes, `myId` is an int containing the processes' rank, `tag` is an int, `domain.field` is a `vector<char>`.
The other necessary variables are defined like this:

```
vector<vector <long long> > toProc;
toProc.resize(numProcs);
long long sizeToReceive[numProcs];
long long sizeToSend=0;
vector<long long> receiveBuffer;
```

What I am trying to do in the code above is to send the vectors `toProc[j]` to process with `id==j for j=0,...,numProcs-1, j!=myId` on each process.
To achieve this I am sending and receiving the sizes of these vectors in the first two for-loops and sending and receiving the actual data in the 3rd and 4th for-loop. I am using Isend because I obviously want these calls to be non-blocking.

The values in `toProc[j]` are the indices, which have to be set to 1 in the vector domain.field on process j (each process has its own domain.field).

My question is:
Do you see any potential for unexpected behaviour in my usage of the Isend-Recv policy.

Comment: I don't see an immediate issue, besides maybe spamming too many ongoing requests, but it seems you could greatly simplify and speed up the whole operation via an `MPI_Alltoall` and `MPI_Alltoallv`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will try to implement the same behaviour using `MPI_Alltoall`, how many requests would you consider too many? The error also occurs if I only use 4 processes, can that be already too many?

Comment: Seems I overlooked the quite obvious issue, please see my answer.

Comment: Four requests would be no issue. But if you want a scalable application, you should use the collectives provided by MPI if you are doing stuff with groups of processes. Alot of optimization goes into those collective implementations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reusing a variable for multiple `ISend` requests without waiting for completion.

[MPI Standard](http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-3.0/mpi30-report.pdf): 3.7.2 and 3.7.4 about `MPI_Request_free`

> A nonblocking send call indicates that the system may start copying
>   data out of the send buffer. The sender should not modify any part of
>   the send buffer after a nonblocking send operation is called, until
>   the send completes.

This means, you must not overwrite `sizeToSend` before the send completes.

> Mark the request object for deallocation and set request to
>   MPI_REQUEST_NULL. An ongoing communication that is associated with the
>   request will be allowed to complete. The request will be deallocated
>   only after its completion.

This means, the send is not guaranteed to complete after `MPI_Request_free`.

You could restructure your code to keep `sizeToSend` in a vector, and also keep the open requests in a vector to properly `MPI_Waitall` on them. But I would advise to just use `MPI_Alltoall` and `MPI_Alltoallv` for the whole operation.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I implemented the communication the way you suggested. It does not solve my problem, but at least I have synchronous communication now and I can assume the error has to be somewhere else.

Comment: @Jonas If you can reproduce the other issue with a small example, free to open another question. You could also give [MUST](https://doc.itc.rwth-aachen.de/display/CCP/Project+MUST) a try - it is an MPI correctness checker.

Comment: I found my error, it had nothing to do with MPI.. it was in the line `domain.field[receiveBuffer[k]]=1;`, there needed to be a case differentiation for `receiveBuffer[k]`. But I could only find it because I implemented this part slightly different using your `MPI_Alltoall` sugggestion and the error turned out different. So although your suggestion did not point out the actual error I was looking for, it helped a lot detecting it (and improved my code). So thank you again, mission accomplished :)